# Mimic Chrome's Zoom with CSS Transform Scale()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project with a lot of images contained within a div.
Set up something like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <div id="sub-container">
        <img class="image" src="1.png">
        <img class="image" src="2.png">
        .
        .
        .
        <img class="image" src="n.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to implement a "zoom" feature, to look at all the images from various distances.

```
#sub-container{
    zoom: 0.9;    
}
```

Does exactly what I want (in Chrome, where it's only being used),
but it runs *really* slow.

```
#sub-container{
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);    
}
```

Runs quite fast, but doesn't behave the way I want, and like how `zoom` does.

`zoom` keeps `#sub-container` at 100% width of the parent container's 100% screen width. Even as you zoom out. Causing all the images to wrap correctly to their new sizes and the new available space.

Transform, however, resizes the `#sub-container` to something smaller than the parent container. 
It's not obvious to me what the size-relationship actually is. 
I need to manually resize `#sub-container` to

width: 111.3% at 0.9 scale
width: 125.1% at 0.8 scale,

etc.

for it to fill the parent container correctly.

Does anyone have an idea about how to get `transform` to act like `zoom`, or get `zoom` to run faster? 
And/or figure out what the relationship between `scale` and `width` should be?
Or even just a CSS trick that'll get `#sub-container` to behave the way I want?

Thanks!

Comment: _“It's not obvious to me what the size-relationship actually is”_ - well “125.1% at 0.8 scale” is obviously directly related to 1/8 (0.125), and once we discovered that “logic”, it isn’t that hard to determine that 1/9 and 111.3% probably have the same “close mathematical relationship” ...

Comment: I'm looking for 100%, not close to 99.8 :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: scale(0.7) with width 142.85714285714285% (100/0.7), is off by 4pixels. It's an imprecise approximation of the real width, and I'd like the real width :)

Comment: Well you’re probably simply dealing with rounding issues here - not that much you can do about that to begin with. Not sure what _exactly_ you want to achieve here in the end (proper example missing; please see [mcve]), but with what we know so far I’d rather say that likely neither zoom nor translate might be the correct tool for the job to begin with.

Comment: What do you think is missing from my question? There are no rounding errors using zoom, but it's just really slow, compared to translate.